# How to tell template match to not run on specific text that's part of a span?

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

I need this script to run on all files that do not contain the text behavioral_science that's included in the span called atom:tag.

Here's the template match in my script:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Step-by-Step'][not(contains(ancestor::xhtml:li[@property = 'ktp:question'],'behavioral_sciences'))]">
```

This is the span line in my HTML:

```
<span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">behavioral_sciences</span>
```

The script right now is looking for any text containing behavioral_science but I need to only look for behavioral_science that's part of the atom:tag span. What am I missing in my XSLT code?

This is more of the HTML code Im running the XSLT script on:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ktp-question-set" data-uuid="90dcafa425ef42dca522211db2db1f1f">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="default" href="../../assets/css/main.css" />
        <title>mbeh01001</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ol class="ktp-question-set" data-uuid="0b866e6990f940e8b22d8083bff94248">
            <li id="mbeh01001" property="ktp:question" typeof="ktp:Question" data-uuid="3e34491dfadd46b58de842471aafd503" class="ktp-question">
                <section class="ktp-question-meta" data-uuid="01e5e879ddda4f4889f1378655a4a3bd">
                    <section property="ktp:metadata" class="ktp-meta" data-uuid="e7e38b9d85e045b4a7e6492b2f286cdb">
                        <span property="atom:content-item-name" class="ktp-meta" data-value="mbeh01001"></span>
                    </section>
                    <section property="ktp:tags" class="ktp-meta" data-uuid="fda3a2342a1546d59cfe4bb37f6198cb">
                        <span property="ktp:interactionType" class="ktp-meta">single-select</span>
                        <span property="ktp:authorName" class="ktp-meta">Ari Morgenstern</span>
                        <span property="ktp:subject" class="ktp-meta">Behavioral Sciences</span>
<span property="jasper:catRef-MCAT2015-QTopic" class="ktp-meta">ps.behsci.bb.infbeh</span><span property="atom:tag" class="ktp-meta">behavioral_sciences</span>
                    </section>
                </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is the full template match code in my XSLT script:

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Step-by-Step'][not(.//xhtml:span[@property = 'atom:tag' and contains(., 'behavioral_sciences')])]">
        <xsl:variable name="separate_class" select="tokenize(@class,'\s')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$separate_class='jasper-exclude'">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="concat('atom-exclude ',$separate_class[not(contains(.,'jasper-exclude'))])"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>                 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* except @class | node()"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>     
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block any such `span` from producing output then usually doing `<xsl:template match="span[@property = 'atom:tag' and . = 'behavioral_sciences']"/>` or with `contains` as `<xsl:template match="span[@property = 'atom:tag' and contains(., 'behavioral_sciences')]"/>` achieves that.

It is not clear how that `span` relates to that template also given and its element `section` but that pattern rewritten to look for any `span` descendants would be

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Step-by-Step'][not(.//xhtml:span[@property = 'atom:tag' and contains(., 'behavioral_sciences')])]">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Unfortunately the script is still processing even when the behavioral_science tag is present. Any suggestion what could be causing that to happen?

Comment: @mjwolff1, shows us minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT, output you want and the one you get, it is not possible to tell from those two snippets what you want to achieve or what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: I added more of the code to the original question. Please let me know if that helps.

Comment: @mjwolff1, is there any `xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Step-by-Step']` at all in that posted input? And you haven't posted the output you get versus the one you want.

Comment: Yes, `xhtml:section[@data-title = 'Step-by-Step']` exists in all the HTML files. The only change I need to occur in the output is jasper-exclude changes to atom-exclude in that Step-by-Step section. I don't want any changes to occur when the behavioral_sciences tag is present. Those HTML files should remain as is when the script sees that tag.